# Predicate fails with fetching object with attribute type of "NSDate" object from Core Data

Tags: core-data, nsdate, nspredicate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

Date that i am receiving from internet is of the format like:

"2014-12-01T20:00:00Z"

i am Storing date with this format in core data..Attribute type is also "Nsdate" type..

```
- (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormate
{

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'dd'-'MM'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZ"];
}
```

Getting start time of [NSDate Date] by using

```
- (NSDate *)cc_dateByMovingToBeginningOfDay
{
  unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
  NSDateComponents* parts = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:self];
  [parts setHour:0];
  [parts setMinute:0];
  [parts setSecond:0];
  return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:parts];
}
```

and end time of [NSDate Date] by using:

```
- (NSDate *)cc_dateByMovingToEndOfDay
{
  unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
  NSDateComponents* parts = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:self];
  [parts setHour:23];
  [parts setMinute:59];
  [parts setSecond:59];
  return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:parts];
}
```

and fetching with this one:

```
- (void)ObjectsFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((due_at > %@) AND (due_at < %@))",fromDate, toDate];
}
```

But record is always zero.as i know that in my today date i have multiple records in data base..i dont know why this happens..

i have also used NSComparisonResult for dates But no record is Between date.

SO please help me out in this..

Comment: i have done NSComparisonResult like this way but it fails as well..
static BOOL IsDateBetweenInclusive(NSDate *date, NSDate *begin, NSDate *end)
{
    return [date compare:begin] != NSOrderedAscending && [date compare:end] != NSOrderedDescending;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format is wrong. The "Z" in "2014-12-01T20:00:00Z" is a "ISO8601 time zone format", and that requires "ZZZZZ" in the date format:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'dd'-'MM'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZZZ"];
```

otherwise `dateFromString:` will return `nil`.

See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns
for more information.